# how to get past cross origin error for http calls from ionic

Tags: angularjs, cross-domain, ionic-framework

I have been trying to call a HTTP GET URL from my ionic app. I am hitting cross-origin error

I got past that error on my Angular.JS app by using Factory. and also got past that on Meteor app by moving the call to server side i.e. by defining them under Meteor.methods()

However i am not able to get past the error on ionic even after using module.factory

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS provides **'JSONP'** service as part of the **[$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)** module for achieving cross domain remote requests. Maybe you can use it.

Comment: can you paste me some snippet as an example?